# Using Add-StorageTableRow to add a row in azure table

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-powershell

I am writing a powershell script to add a row in azure table, which is not running. Below is the code and the error i am getting.

Code:

```
  function add-table-entity()
 {
$entity = '[{"AD_Domain":"xyz.onmicrosoft.com","osVersion":"Windows 7","status":"OK"}]'

foreach ($ent in ($entity | ConvertFrom-Json) )
 {

    Add-StorageTableRow -table $tableName -partitionKey $partitionKey -rowKey "$rowkey" -property @{"AD_Domain"=$ent.AD_Domain}

 }
```

}

Error:

```
 You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRmStorageTable\1.0.0.23\AzureRmStorageTableCoreHelper.psm1:191 char:11
```

I checked if any of the variable is null or not defined, but that is not the case. Any idea what is happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the table object to instead of table name in your script.

You could get the table object in this way.

```
$storageTable = Get-AzureStorageTable –Name $tableName –Context $ctx
```

Please have a try to test it with following code.

```
function add-table-entity()
{
$entity = '[{"AD_Domain":"xyz.onmicrosoft.com","osVersion":"Windows 7","status":"OK"}]'

    foreach ($ent in ($entity | ConvertFrom-Json) )
    {

        Add-StorageTableRow -table $storageTable -partitionKey $partitionKey -rowKey "$rowkey" -property @{"AD_Domain"=$ent.AD_Domain}

    }
 }
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

For more information about how to work with Azure Storage Tables from PowerShell, please refer to this [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/paulomarques/2017/01/17/working-with-azure-storage-tables-from-powershell/).